# Calling the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a new project by doing `rails new start_app`. I want to show the view `index.html.erb` on the incoming url `localhost:3000/iamonweb`. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Create a route, create a controller, read [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). While your question is on-topic (mostly?), it shows absolutely no research effort in an attempt to solve your given problem. We're here to help you solve, not solve for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Some people first edit config/route.rb, I preferly first create controller iamonweb. Instead of vi, you could use visual editor or IDE.

```
    $ rails g controller iamonweb
     create  app/controllers/iamonweb_controller.rb
     invoke  erb
     create    app/views/iamonweb
     invoke  test_unit
     create    test/controllers/iamonweb_controller_test.rb
     invoke  helper
     create    app/helpers/iamonweb_helper.rb
     invoke    test_unit
     invoke  assets
       invoke    coffee
    create      app/assets/javascripts/iamonweb.coffee
    invoke    scss
    create      app/assets/stylesheets/iamonweb.scss
```

And next edit controller/iamonweb_controller.rb

```
   $ ~/ror/start_app $ vi app/controllers/iamonweb_controller.rb 
    class IamonwebController < ApplicationController
     def index
      @msg = "I am on web"
     end
    end

    $ ~/ror/start_app $ vi app/views/iamonweb/index.html.erb 
    <%= @msg %>
```

Last configuration on config/route.rb, just add this line.
        $ ~/ror/start_app $ vi config/routes.rb

```
     Rails.application.routes.draw do
        get '/iamonweb' => 'iamonweb#index'
        ...other comments..follows
```

Finally,start server with below command in start_app directory. ror directory is my rubyonrails playing directory.

```
           $ ~/ror/start_app $ rails s
```

With browser,,go to http://localhost:3000/iamonweb/